# How to handle this XML response (SOAP:Envelope) correctly to get at least a DataView/DataTable?

Tags: c#, xml, soap

i have a problem again with a XML document, which i receive as a respond from a web-request (HP Service Manager).

This is the XML response:

```xml
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<RetrieveSDToDoListResponse 
message="Success" returnCode="0" 
schemaRevisionDate="2015-09-24" 
schemaRevisionLevel="0" status="SUCCESS" 
xmlns="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7" 
xmlns:cmn="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7/Common" 
xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7 /SDToDo.xsd">
<instance query="" recordid="CM00106862 - cm3r" uniquequery="record.id=&quot;CM00106862&quot; and itemType=&quot;cm3r&quot;">
<TodoNumber type="String">CM00106862</TodoNumber>
<ToDoModule type="String">cm3r</ToDoModule>
<ToDoStatus type="String">submitted</ToDoStatus>
<ToDoDescription type="String">Portactivation Server SCHWARTZ3 C6000 Request and Network Configuration Request</ToDoDescription>
<ToDoAssignmentGroup type="String">XL/IOC GERMANY</ToDoAssignmentGroup>
<ToDoAssigneeName type="String">p591392</ToDoAssigneeName>
</instance>
<instance query="" recordid="IM02086084 - probsummary" uniquequery="record.id=&quot;IM02086084&quot; and itemType=&quot;probsummary&quot;">
<TodoNumber type="String">IM02086084</TodoNumber>
<ToDoModule type="String">probsummary</ToDoModule>
<ToDoStatus type="String">In Charge</ToDoStatus>
<ToDoDescription type="String">WBI-FN Operating rights for XL10033 expired?</ToDoDescription>
<ToDoAssignmentGroup type="String">XL/IOC GERMANY</ToDoAssignmentGroup>
<ToDoAssigneeName type="String">p707112</ToDoAssigneeName>
</instance>
<instance query="" recordid="IM02135674 - probsummary" uniquequery="record.id=&quot;IM02135674&quot; and itemType=&quot;probsummary&quot;">
<TodoNumber type="String">IM02135674</TodoNumber>
<ToDoModule type="String">probsummary</ToDoModule>
<ToDoStatus type="String">In Charge</ToDoStatus>
<ToDoDescription type="String">G00PSMP1: Event ID: 432, FILE, ERROR =&gt; SollShares =&gt; 430 =&gt; 432</ToDoDescription>
<ToDoAssignmentGroup type="String">XL/IOC GERMANY</ToDoAssignmentGroup>
<ToDoAssigneeName type="String">p518731</ToDoAssigneeName>
</instance>
<instance query="" recordid="TM00059273 - cm3t" uniquequery="record.id=&quot;TM00059273&quot; and itemType=&quot;cm3t&quot;">
<TodoNumber type="String">TM00059273</TodoNumber>
<ToDoModule type="String">cm3t</ToDoModule>
<ToDoStatus type="String">submitted</ToDoStatus>
<ToDoDescription type="String">Tributum Server Downtime - Tivoli Task</ToDoDescription>
<ToDoAssignmentGroup type="String">XL/IOC GERMANY</ToDoAssignmentGroup>
<ToDoAssigneeName type="String">xl10033</ToDoAssigneeName>
</instance>
<instance query="" recordid="TM00059274 - cm3t" uniquequery="record.id=&quot;TM00059274&quot; and itemType=&quot;cm3t&quot;">
<TodoNumber type="String">TM00059274</TodoNumber>
<ToDoModule type="String">cm3t</ToDoModule>
<ToDoStatus type="String">submitted</ToDoStatus>
<ToDoDescription type="String">Tributum disable mainframe ressource</ToDoDescription>
<ToDoAssignmentGroup type="String">XL/IOC GERMANY</ToDoAssignmentGroup>
<ToDoAssigneeName type="String">xl10033</ToDoAssigneeName>
</instance>
<instance query="" recordid="TM00059278 - cm3t" uniquequery="record.id=&quot;TM00059278&quot; and itemType=&quot;cm3t&quot;">
<TodoNumber type="String">TM00059278</TodoNumber>
<ToDoModule type="String">cm3t</ToDoModule>
<ToDoStatus type="String">submitted</ToDoStatus>
<ToDoDescription type="String">Tributum Server Downtime - Tivoli Task</ToDoDescription>
<ToDoAssignmentGroup type="String">XL/IOC GERMANY</ToDoAssignmentGroup>
<ToDoAssigneeName type="String">xl10033</ToDoAssigneeName>
</instance>
<instance query="" recordid="TM00059280 - cm3t" uniquequery="record.id=&quot;TM00059280&quot; and itemType=&quot;cm3t&quot;">
<TodoNumber type="String">TM00059280</TodoNumber>
<ToDoModule type="String">cm3t</ToDoModule>
<ToDoStatus type="String">submitted</ToDoStatus>
<ToDoDescription type="String">Tributum disable mainframe ressource</ToDoDescription>
<ToDoAssignmentGroup type="String">XL/IOC GERMANY</ToDoAssignmentGroup>
<ToDoAssigneeName type="String">xl10033</ToDoAssigneeName>
</instance>
<instance query="" recordid="TM00059504 - cm3t" uniquequery="record.id=&quot;TM00059504&quot; and itemType=&quot;cm3t&quot;">
<TodoNumber type="String">TM00059504</TodoNumber>
<ToDoModule type="String">cm3t</ToDoModule>
<ToDoStatus type="String">submitted</ToDoStatus>
<ToDoDescription type="String">Tributum disable mainframe ressource</ToDoDescription>
<ToDoAssignmentGroup type="String">XL/IOC GERMANY</ToDoAssignmentGroup>
<ToDoAssigneeName type="String">p568003</ToDoAssigneeName>
</instance>
</RetrieveSDToDoListResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

i tried with following code, but i'm at the end by looping thru the existing nodes. 
I know there should be a simple way to get all items from the nodes "instance" and all child items.

At the end i need a DataView or a DataTable to go on with my application.

```
public static string gettextfromWebserviceItems(string result)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();


        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(result);
        var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        ns.AddNamespace("SOAP-ENV", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        //XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/RetrieveSDToDoListResponse/instance", ns);
        XmlNodeList nodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("instance");

        List<string> elementNamesList = new List<string>();
        elementNamesList.Add("TodoNumber");
        elementNamesList.Add("ToDoModule");
        elementNamesList.Add("ToDoStatus");
        elementNamesList.Add("ToDoDescription");
        elementNamesList.Add("ToDoAssignmentGroup");
        elementNamesList.Add("ToDoAssigneeName");

        foreach (XmlNodeList node in nodes)
        {

            //foreach (XmlAttribute v in node.Attributes)
            //{
            //    var value = v;
            //    //Do the processing

            //}


        }
```

if there is a simple solution with a external DLL like SAX or whatever, so let me know...

Thank you in advance,
and best wishes from Munich

Comment: Did you try _Add Service Reference_ to the project and automatically generate a set of classes? It's easy and doesn't need to manually parse soap envelope.

Answer (score 0):

An XSD file can be converted into a C# class definition relatively easily. The XML you've posted has the following attribute in it: `xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7 /SDToDo.xsd"`.

With this you can either parse the XSD into a C# using `xsd.exe` for use with `XmlSerializer` (a terrible idea and I wouldn't do it), OR you can use the C# classes as a basis to work from to create your own model and translator without using `XmlSerializer` (using `XNode` rather than `XmlDocument` API).

Once it's in object form, it'd be relatively easy to turn into a `DataTable` or `DataView` (or you could do it directly, whichever you prefer).

Answer (score 0):

Not very agree with previous speakers. Yes, it will be in object form, but is not so easy to convert array of objects into DataTable. 
In your case you you're in luck with your envelope, the xml is exact representation of DataTable xml format, you can just use ReadXml method

```
// your code, practically unchanged
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(result);
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("SOAP-ENV", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
ns.AddNamespace("XZ", "http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7");
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/XZ:RetrieveSDToDoListResponse", ns);

if(node!=null)
{
    //define your table
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("TodoNumber", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ToDoModule", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ToDoStatus", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ToDoDescription", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ToDoAssignmentGroup", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ToDoAssigneeName", typeof(string));
    dt.TableName = "instance";

    string content = "<DocumentElement>" +
        //DIRTY HACK TO REMOVE NAMESPACE
            node.InnerXml.Replace("xmlns=\"http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7\"", "")
         + "</DocumentElement>";

    //this code makes the trick
    using(MemoryStream  ms=new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (content)))
    {
        dt.ReadXml(ms);    
    }

}
```

Comment: i tried it in many ways... but this works perfectly for me!!!
many thanks vitalygolub